# Can two smooth submanifolds intersect transversally on an almost Cantor set?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

*Note: In the following, all submanifolds are assumed to be smoothly embedded, i.e. the image of a smooth embedding.*

**Definition:** A *Cantor subset* of a topological space $X$ is a closed, nowhere dense subset of $X$ with no isolated points.

**Problem set up:**

Let $M$ be a compact, finite dimensional smooth manifold without boundary, and let $K$ and $N$ be submanifolds of $M$ with $\dim K + \dim N > \dim M$.

Suppose that $K \cap N$ is a Cantor subset of another submanifold $J$ of $M$ with $1 \leq \dim J \leq \dim K + \dim N - \dim M$.

Denote by $T$ the subset of $K \cap N$ on which $K$ and $N$ intersect transversally.

> **Question:** Can $T$ have nonzero measure in $J$?

Comment: I mean that the tangent spaces of the two submanifolds span the tangent spaces of the original manifold at that point. Since $K$ and $N$ are not guaranteed to intersect transversally at every point, the intersection is not guaranteed to be a smooth submanifold.

Comment: If $M$ is an $m$-fold, $K$ and $N$ are submanifolds of dimension $k$ and $n$, and $K$ meets $N$ transversely at $x$, then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ such that $U \cap K \cap N$ is an $(k+n-m)$-fold, right? In particular, it can't be a Cantor set. I think I must be missing something.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Oh I wasn’t aware of that result. Must the intersection have dimension $(k + n - m)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Here is the first reference I found http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/week4.pdf

Comment: PS If you are not imposing transversality, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73334